# iPhone does not react to charger unless turned off

Tags: iphone, charging

I have my iPhone 5S for less than a week. I have charged it fully only once. Cable, charger and phone are new and from the box.
When I connect it to the USB charger it does not display the lighting symbol nor does it charge. However, if the cable is inserted before it turns on or if I restart the iPhone with the cable inserted, then the charging begins. Taking the phone away from the cable for even a second spoils the magic, so you can imagine how annoying it is. I am suspecting this is a software error.

Connection to MacBook does not work either. When cable is inserted nothing happens. No app can see the phone and vice versa. This does not change even after the restart.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you can demonstrate this at an Apple store, Apple will replace it.

Comment: Thank you @Mark! In fact, that is what I did and what they did. The cable was inoperative.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it worked out for you.